# Registry returning null

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to get the registry but its always returning null and i dont know why

```
class Extension extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template  {

        protected $_urlBuilder;
        protected $_storeManager;
        protected $productRepository;
        protected $_coreRegistry;
        public function __contruct(

            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager

        ){

            $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
            $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;

            $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;

        }



    const ICON_EXTENSION = '.gif';
    const URL_ICON  =  'images/productextension/';


public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
}
```

Why is my registry null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code

try to create a new block file and replace my code and get the current product id. if it works then check in your code where you wrong.

```
<?php 
namespace Vedor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class ProductDetailNew extends Template
{
    private $_registry;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Config $pageConfig
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Config $pageConfig,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
    * @return Int
    **/
    public function getCurrentProductId()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
    } 
}
?>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have other question, why does my layout breaks when i add an block into my `catalog_product_view.xml`? After adding 1 block my page layout converts to 3 columns layout instead of 1 column why is that?